# If someone holds an Afghani passport, an Italian ID card and a visa, can they travel to Ireland with the Afghani passport?

Tags: ireland, schengen-visas

If someone holds an Afghani passport, an Italian ID card and a visa, valid for 5 years, can they travel to Ireland with the Afghani passport? Or do they need a visa if they don't have an Italian travel document, but only an Afghani passport?

Comment: What is the purpose of the picture here?

Comment: Italy is in the Schengen area. Ireland is not. So the Italian residence permit does not automatically cover Ireland.

Comment: The residence permit _permesso di soggiorno_ is valid to travel to Schengen states, but it is not enough to travel to non-Schengen countries such as the UK or Ireland.

Answer (score 3):

Would have to be an Italian National Identity card known as, Carta d'Identità Elettronica (Electronic identity card, CIE). Seen as though you're only on a 5 year visa I'm guessing it's just a resident card. You will have to apply for a visa, [this visa](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Visit%20Tourist) should be good for you. Good news is you have a valid visa for a strict visa country so that boosts your changes of getting a visa.